# select objects by joining relationships with doctrine DQL

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have three entities: `Project`, `RequestMatcher`, and `Response`. Here is how they are related:

```
$project->getRequestMatchers(); // Project has many RequestMatchers

$requestMatcher->getActiveResponse(); // RequestMatcher has one active Response
```

How can i write DQL to get all active `Response`s for a `Project`?

```
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery(
        "SELECT resp FROM $responseClass resp
               JOIN $requestMatcherClass req WITH req.project = :project
               WHERE resp.id IN(req.active_response_id)"
    );

    $query->setParameter('project', $project);
```

I'm getting the following exception though:

```
[Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException]                                 
  [Syntax Error] line 0, col 230: Error: Expected Literal, got 'req'
```

I've also tried this with the same result:

```
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery(
        "SELECT resp FROM $responseClass resp
               LEFT JOIN resp.requestMatcher req WITH req.project = :project
               WHERE resp IN(req.activeResponse)"
    );
```

This is the sql that will give me the id's

```
select active_response_id from (
  select active_response_id from request_matchers where project_id = 1
) t
```

Comment: Just a wild guess since I don't have a testing environment available, but did you try `SELECT resp FROM project p JOIN p.requestMatcher rm JOIN rm.response resp WHERE p = :project`?

Comment: i get a the following with that: `Cannot select entity through identification variables without choosing at least one root entity alias. `

Comment: What version of Doctrine are you using? I think this became more flexible with the latest stable.
One more shot after seeing the SQL: `SELECT req.response FROM requestMatcher req WHERE req.project = :project` You could skip the outer select IMO.

Comment: i feel like you're close. Now i'm getting: `[Semantical Error] line 0, col 28 near 'response': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression`. If i change `req.response` to `IDENTITY(req.response)`, i get the correct id's back.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not convinced this is the best way to do it but i solved this with the following:

```
    $query = "SELECT resp FROM $responseClass resp
              WHERE resp.id IN (
                  SELECT IDENTITY(req.activeResponse) FROM $requestMatcherClass req
                  WHERE req.project = :project
              )";
```

Comment: I was just about to write the same :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using the QueryBuilder object, something like :

```
$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('YourBundle:Project')->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->join('p.requestMatchers', 'rm', \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH, 'rm.project = :project')
    ->join('rm.activeReponse', 'ar')
    ->addSelect('rm.*')
    ->addSelect('ar.*')
    ->setParameter('project', $project)
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute();
```